# AngularJS: How to use the ngRepeat directive together with arrays and subarrays?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's assume there is an array of categories. Contained within this array, for each category, there is a variable number of images. Additionally, each image has a sub-array of paths for varying sizes of each image. Listed below is an example.

```
$scope.categories = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Fashion", "images": [
    { "id": 1, "paths": [
      { "id": 1, "pathThumb":"thumbnail_A.jpg"},
      { "id": 2, "pathFull":"full_size_A.jpg"}
    ]}
  ]},
  { "id": 2, "name": "Sunsets", "images": [
    { "id": 1, "paths": [
      { "id": 1, "pathThumb":"thumbnail_B.jpg"}
      { "id": 2, "pathFull":"full_size_B.jpg"}
    ]},
    { "id": 2, "paths": [
      { "id": 1, "pathThumb":"thumbnail_C.jpg"}
      { "id": 2, "pathFull":"full_size_C.jpg"}
    ]}
  ]}
];
```

I would like to use the AngularJS ngRepeat directive to loop through the above data to produce the following

```
<div class="item fashion">
  <a href="full_size_A.jpg"><img src="thumbnail_A.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="item sunset">
  <a href="full_size_B.jpg"><img src="thumbnail_B.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="item sunset">
  <a href="full_size_C.jpg"><img src="thumbnail_C.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I assume it would look something like the following:

```
<div class="item {{category.name}}" ng-repeat="...">
  <a href="{{category.image.path.pathFull}}"><img src="{{category.image.path.pathThumb}}"></a>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to loop through an array with sub-array and extract the appropriate data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in categories">
    <div ng-repeat="image in item.images">
        <a ng-href="{{image.paths[1].pathFull}}">
            <img ng-src="{{image.paths[0].pathThumb}}">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use a wrapper container in order to get subarray of categories..

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <div class="item {{category.name | lowercase}}" ng-repeat="image in category.images">
      <a ng-href="{{image.paths[1].path}}">
        <img ng-src="{{image.paths[0].path}}">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here I used **dynamic class** with `ng-class` and using **lowercase filter** to get lowercase version of name string as class...

using `ng-src` as `src` attribute of `img` is important here because sometimes given interpolate (`{{something}}`) cause fail to load resource, because of data is not fecthed...

same thing for ng-href...

here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/YgJ02OObZsrQ4R0QPT3h?p=preview)...